# Java send mail graph api oAuth2

Tags: java, spring, api, maven, sendmail

I am trying to send an email with the microsoft graph api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example-3--create-a-message-with-a-file-attachment-and-send-the-message, but I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: BadRequest
Error message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.
```

How i have to do for specify email adress from ?
This is my code, i get my token with Modern Auth, and after i try to send e-mail

```
final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .tenantId(tenant)
                    .build();

            final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(clientSecretCredential);

            final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
              GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();

            Message message = new Message();
            message.subject = "Meet for lunch?";
            ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
            body.contentType = BodyType.TEXT;
            body.content = "The new cafeteria is open.";
            message.body = body;
            LinkedList<Recipient> toRecipientsList = new LinkedList<Recipient>();
            Recipient toRecipients = new Recipient();
            EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
            emailAddress.address = "meganb@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
            toRecipients.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            toRecipientsList.add(toRecipients);
            message.toRecipients = toRecipientsList;
            LinkedList<Attachment> attachmentsList = new LinkedList<Attachment>();
            FileAttachment attachments = new FileAttachment();
            attachments.name = "attachment.txt";
            attachments.contentType = "text/plain";
            attachments.contentBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh");
            attachmentsList.add(attachments);
            AttachmentCollectionResponse attachmentCollectionResponse = new AttachmentCollectionResponse();
            attachmentCollectionResponse.value = attachmentsList;
            AttachmentCollectionPage attachmentCollectionPage = new AttachmentCollectionPage(attachmentCollectionResponse, null);
            message.attachments = attachmentCollectionPage;

            graphClient.me()
                .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
                    .newBuilder()
                    .withMessage(message)
                    .withSaveToSentItems(null)
                    .build())
                .buildRequest()
                .post();
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it looks for a method Preconditions.checkPositionIndex(II)I which takes 2 arguments and cannot find a such method, can you check what exactly is called here - com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.indexIn(CharMatcher.java:689)?
I presume something might be wrong with dependency versions, which versions of dependencies do you use? In particular which version of Guava?

Comment: @VitalyChura yes, i fixed, i was using another library, thank you

Comment: then write an answer and. accept it) so that people who encounter that problem also knew how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the token generated don't have scopes which you specify. You can even verify that by pasting your token on jwt.io. You need to change the permissions of your application so to add scopes in the token generated to use the me endpoint. Also without doing this you won't be able to hit Users endpoint as well